# Выполнение функции в условии if

Tags: c++, c

Если я выполняю функцию в условии

```
if (function() == 0) {...}
```

она выполнится абсолютно также как и вне условия, это не влечет никаких побочных эффектов?

Чем такой вызов отличается от вызова вне условия?

Comment: Выполнится. Вот если бы у вас было что-то типа `if (x > a && function() == 0)` - тут может быть так, что и не выполнится из-за сокращенного вычисления логического условия...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если функция **выполняется**, то она выполняется точно так же, как и вне условия.

Вся тонкость в "если выполняется" - в сложном выражении с операторами `&&` и `||`, для которых справедливо сокращенное вычислоение, она может не выполниться. Сокращенное вычисление - это если вычисляя условия, в некоторый момент становится очевидно значение полного условия, то остальные части не вычисляются. Например, в `A && B`, если вычисление `A` дает `false`, каким бы ни было `B` - результат будет `false`. В таком случае `B` не вычисляется.

Так что в

```
if (i == 0 && function() == 0)
```

при `i`, не равном 0,  `function()` вычисляться просто не будет.

Comment: Позанудствую: `&&` и `||` делают то же самое и вне условий `if`-ов.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat У меня не сказано, что они только в `if` - просто "в сложном условии". Но, чтоб не занудствовать, исправлю на "выражении".

Answer (score 3):

Нет, это ни на что не влияет. Никакой разницы нет.

---

В соседнем ответе вспомнили про [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) - свойство операторов `&&` и `||` не вычислять второй операнд (и не вызывать в нем функции), и первого операнда достаточно для определения результата.

Но это происходит везде - и внутри условий `if`-ов, и снаружи.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/541633)

Comment: @return Поясните пожалуйста, каким боком это не ответ? Какую информаци нужно в него добавить, чтобы это стало ответом?

Comment: ИМХО, это комментарий. +тут уже есть комментарий, получивший 3 плюса. вопрос исчерпан комментарием. зачем писать ещё 1 ответ-комментарий — не понятно

Comment: @return Нет, это ответ. ТС спрашивает, в чем разница, а я *отвечаю*, что этой разницы нет. Флаг "не является ответом" здесь не подходит. Вот примеры "ответов", для которых он бы подошел: "это написано в любой книжке по С++", "зачем вызывать функцию в условии", "мне тоже интересен этот вопрос", и так далее. [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] *"вопрос исчерпан комментарием"* Он не исчерпан комментарием, потому что коммент нельзя отметить галочкой и этим отметить вопрос как решенный. К тому же, мне не очень нравится формулировка комментария, потому что создается впечатление, что `&&` имеет какое-то особое поведение именно в условии `if`, а это не так.

Comment: да? только несмотря на всё это был принят ответ написанный позже, зато в котором всё более подробно расписано

Comment: @return А при чем тут это? Куда ставить галочку решает только автор вопроса, мой ответ от этого хуже не стал.

Comment: причина создания ответа от Mikhailo в том, что он хотел дополнить ваш ответ. при этом галку получило именно дополнение. значит, ответ с дополнением оказался понятнее спрашивающему и, как следствие, лучше. в ответе должно быть пояснение к выводу, который вы в этом ответе озвучиваете. тут же это выглядит, как будто вы отвечаете профессионалу, который просто решил удостоверится, прав ли он или нет: ему пояснения не нужны. судя по содержимому вопроса, пояснения в ответе как раз таки очень даже нужны

Comment: @return, (1) принятый ответ не всегда лучше остальных. (2) В данном случае, по моему скромному мнению, ответ HolyBlackCat лучше, потому что в нем приводится ссылка на short-circuit evaluation. (3) Данное сообщение отвечает на вопрос «чем обычные вызов отличается от вызова в условии», значит это ответ.

Comment: @eanmos Справедливости ради, ссылку я вставил только что.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, в любом случае, даже первая редакция ответа была ответом :)

Comment: @return Отредактировал. Но вы поймите, дело не в том, хороший мой ответ или плохой - это все равно ответ. Если считаете его плохим, ставьте минус, а не флаг. Посмотрите [здесь](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/2752075), когда стоит использовать флаг "не ответ".

Comment: по этой категории ваш ответ (до правки) относился к "Low-Quality Answer"... для меня комментарий это комментарий — просто реплика, а ответ это ответ — развёрнутый. теперь буду знать, что Low-Quality Answers это не комментарии

Answer (score 1):

Также скажу, что в С++ может быть код, в котором вызов функции не приводит к её выполнению. Например, если вызов функции - это аргумент `decltype`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int func()
{
    std::cout << "Hello from func!" << std::endl;
    return 123;
}

int main()
{
    decltype(func()) var;
    return 0;
}
```

Этот код ничего не отобразит на экране, потому что чтобы определить тип возвращаемого значения, можно просто посмотреть его не вызывая функцию.